# Successfully run a C# project on client machine with proper functioning Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports, .net-4.7

I made my project in C# Visual Studio 2017 using .Net Framework 4.7 and SQL Server 2008. Now I tried to run my project in the client machine which has Windows 10 installed on it. After installing I ran the .exe file, all my functions are running smoothly except my **Crystal Reports Viewer**.

Comment: What happened when you try to open Crystal reports?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers but I solved it , the issue was in version of Crystal report as it needed CR V13.0.25.134 for 64 bit but I was using CR V13.0.26 , so yeah I made it through. Thanks again everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SAP runtime for Crystal reports on the client machine

Answer (score -1):

You should have install SQL server on your client machine to make the database working similarly you are required to download the client tool for SAP report. So instal **Crystal Report Runtime** for client machine and it will let you open your reports on your client machine without any error.